# Improper integral on a finite value and behaviour of the primitive

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals

Say I have a function $f(x)$ defined on $(-\infty,a)\cup(a,+\infty)$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = +\infty$. What happens if I try to calculate the primitive $g(x) =\int f(x)dx$ , should $g(x) = +\infty$ with $x \geq a$ if the integral is divergent at $a$?

I think it doesn't exist , but I'm not sure how to prove it.

EDIT :

I was confusing myself, the only problem with this function is in the calculation of any integral of such function $\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} f(x) $ such that (assuming $x_1 \leq x_2 $ )  $x_1 \leq a$ and $x_2 \geq a$ because it's unbounded on $a$ , so it's not integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $f(x) := \frac{1}{|x|}$. An antiderivative is $g(x) = \text{sgn}(x) \ln(|x|) + 0$. $\frac{1}{|x|}$ is defined on $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, +\infty)$. Both $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{|x|} dx$ and $\int_{-1}^0 \frac{1}{|x|} dx$ are divergent. But $g(x) = \ln(x) \neq +\infty$ for every $x \gt 0$.